# Grouping object.function into a single class or "array type form"

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, derived-class

Lets suppose I have a couple of classes with derived classes:

```
class A {
protected:
...
private:
....
public:

foo1();
foo2();
foo3();
};



Class B : public A {
/*same thing here with variables...*/
public:
doo1();
doo2();

};

Class C : public A {
/*same thing here with variables...*/
public:
loo1();
loo2();

};
```

Then in my main I create objects and call the functions as follows:

```
B obj_b;
C obj_c;

obj_b.doo1();
obj_b.doo2();
obj_c.loo1();
obj_c.loo2();
```

I was wondering if there was a way to group all of these together (without the use of a function that includes all of the functions within that class), into a class or some sort of array structure (not necessarily an array for this. 
By array type I mean: int array[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};  equivalent in this case to something like = {obj_b.doo1(), obj_c.loo1()}; etc.

Is theres any way this is possible in c++?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: grouping functions from all classes into one class or organizing them